# How to convert data type according to a given list

Tags: r

I need to convert data class for many vectors according to a given list. is there any command or function?

I have tried as() command, but it can not convert character to factor.

for example

```
a1<-c(1,2,3,4)
a2<-c("a","b","a","b")
a3<-c("1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4")


type<-c("character","factor","numeric")

as(a1,type[1])
as(a2,type[2])
as(a3,type[3])
```

I got error: no method or default for coercing “character” to “factor”

Comment: Just FYI when you use \`\`\` to mark where code formatting should begin, whatever comes next is used to tell markdown what language the syntax highlighting should follow. So by having no newline after the backticks, your text said that `a1` was the name of the language and didn't include it as a line of code

Answer (score 3):

The `as` method may not work correctly with `character` to `factor`, instead a more easier option is to `paste` the `as.` as prefix, `get` the function and apply on the `vector`

```
Map(function(x, y) get(y)(x), mget(paste0("a", 1:3)), paste0("as.", type))
```

Answer (score 3):

A `purrr-base` possibility:

```
types<-c("character","factor","numeric")

types <- paste0("as.", types)
purrr::map2(list(a2, a3), types[-1], function(x,y) do.call(y,list(x)))
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] a b a b
Levels: a b

[[2]]
[1] 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
```

Data:

```
a2<-c("a","b","a","b")
a3<-c("1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4")
```